# Average points given a win ratio

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm playing a game in which there is an event that I can keep playing until I reach $3$ loses or $7$ wins. You get points for every win. $0$ wins $5$ points, $1$ win $10$ points, $2$ wins $20$ points... $7$ wins $95$ points.

I'd like to know given my win rate what is the average number of points that I'm getting.

So what I've thought is the following:

I have the probability of wining $pw$, and of losing $pl$. We get the probability of going $0-3, 1-3,\cdots, 7-2, 7-1, 7-0$ like:

Probability of going $0-3$: $pw^0 * pl^3$

Probability of going $2-3$: $pw^2 * pl^3$

Then we get the points for each probability:

Probability of getting $5$ points: $(pw^0 * pl^3) * 5$

Then we sum all the points to get the average points for our win rate.

Comment: "Probability of going 2-3: $p_w^2\cdot p_\ell^3$"  No, that is the probability of winning the first, winning the second, losing the third, losing the fourth, losing the fifth.  You could also have a record of 2-3 by winning the first losing the second, losing the third, winning the fourth, losing the fifth or some other order.  What remains constant is that in any time you stop playing because of losing, the very last game is always a loss.  The prior games however could occur in whatever order.

Comment: And how can I calculate the possibilities, with permutations or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one way to end up with 0-3. And it's LLL

However, there are more than one ways to end up with 2-3 (e.g. WWLLL, LWLWL, LLWWL). Note that the last match must always be a L. So, you need all the possible combinations of 2 wins and 2 losses. This is `combin(4,2)=6`.

Similarly, there are `combin(7,2)=21` ways to end up with 5-3

Now, regarding the winning cases, they must all end up with a W.
So e.g for record of 7-2, you have `combin(8,2)=28` different ways.

In total you'll have that the average points are:

$\dbinom22pw^0pl^3 + \dbinom32pw^1pl^3+ \dbinom42pw^2pl^3+\dbinom52pw^3pl^3+\dbinom62pw^4pl^3+\dbinom72pw^5pl^3+\dbinom82pw^6pl^3+\dbinom82pw^7pl^2+\dbinom71pw^7pl^1+\dbinom60pw^7pl^0$